# How to get SAML2.0 assertion from ADFS 3 via oauth

Tags: oauth, saml-2.0, adfs3.0

Using /adfs/oauth2/token and /adfs/oauth2/token WS-API, I am able to retrive access_token. But, it’s a JWT and I need SAML2.0 assertion.

How to fetch SAML2.0 assertion from ADFS via oauth? Or, is there a way to convert JWT to SAML 2.0?

Please note I am using ADFS 3.0

Thanks,
Prasad Jana

Comment: Did you find a solution for this issue